# Extract words after the specific word

Tags: c#, split

I got the source code of a webpage and 
I want to get a word after the vi-buybox-watchcount">.

[image: Please click here to see the image]

After the vi-buybox-watchcount"> has 152 number. I want to extract it..

I know only split keyword to do it.But i cannot use  '>' to split it because that source code has so many '>' with digits..

So i try to split it as following but it is getting errors...

```
for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(idlist.Length); i++)
        {
            string url = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/" + idlist[i];
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            // richTextBox2.Text += sr.ReadToEnd();
            string a = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            string source = null;
            source = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
           a.Split('vi-buybox-watchcount">') // this is getting errors
                .Where(m => m.All(char.IsDigit)));
```

Please suggest me a method to extract this number

Comment: Search for _vi-buybox-watchcount">_ to find the start of the number, then search for _<_ to find the end of the number.

Comment: Basically this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 True not only for regexes, but for home-made split-based parsers.

Comment: how to search this words.. I have no idea about it., i am very beginner for this.

Comment: If OP knows exactly what is being looked for then _"parsing HTML"_ is not relevant.

Comment: @Ivan The OP never mentioned regex.

Comment: @bornfromanegg Same applies to home-made split-based parsers.

Comment: @BrianThomas: Use the [IndexOf(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) for the first search, the [IndexOf(string,int)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx) for the secod search and the [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) to extract the number.

Comment: ok Paul I will see what you have sent

Comment: Could CSSSelectors be the way to go here? http://simontimms.com/2014/02/24/parsing-html-in-c-using-css-selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a regular expression instead?

```
String html = ... // your html text
String number = String.Empty; // default value if not found

Match m = Regex.Match(html, @"<span class\=""vi-buybox-watchcount"">([0-9]+?)<\/span>");

if (m.Success)
    number = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: this code is getting errors

Comment: Which one, apart the wrong variable name I just fixed?

Comment: [please check the error] (https://scontent.fcmb2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25591591_380769489039772_7794267392667685431_n.jpg?oh=539ce8d375aa2cbc7c5e94a9647473b4&oe=5ABDA222)

Comment: Ah! So sorry, it should be fixed now! Forgot to escape.

Comment: When using @ operator you must escape double quotes by repeating them.

Comment: but it is not printing correct number

Comment: your code is working

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
string strHTML = "..................<span class=\"'vi-buybox-watchcount\">152</span>";

string strFind = "'vi-buybox-watchcount\">";
int startIndex = strHTML.IndexOf(strFind) + strFind.Length;
int endIndex = strHTML.IndexOf("<", startIndex);
string reqValue = strHTML.Substring(startIndex, endIndex-startIndex);
```

IndexOf will find the start position of the string being looked for, so add the length of that string to find the start of the value. The difference between that & the second string will be the required length to extract.

You may want to add error checking code in the event either string is not found - IndexOf returns -1 if not found.

If there are multiple occurrences, then you could use a loop & the second version of IndexOf with the last found endIndex as the second parameter (initialised to zero).

A possible Linq only solution could be :

```
strHTML.Split(new string[]{strFind}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(x => char.IsDigit(x[0]))
    .Select(y => y.Substring(0,y.IndexOf("<")));
```

Or

```
strHTML.Split(new string[]{strFind}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(y => y.Substring(0,y.IndexOf("<")))
    .Where(m => m.All(char.IsDigit));
```

if you want only numeric values.